# Java string comparsion

Tags: java, string, arrays

I'm trying to implement a simple cesar cipher. I'm having trouble with the function that codes a string based on a new key[]. Here I shown, how I setup my key.

```
private String[] alphabet =  {"a", "b", "c","d", "e", "f","g", "h", "i","j", "k", "l","m", "n", "o",
            "p", "q", "r","s", "t", "u","v", "w", "x","u", "z"};

public String[] CoderNewKey(int shift) {
    _NewKey = null;
    _NewKey = new String[25];

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        _NewKey[i] = alphabet[(i + shift) % 25];
    }
    return _NewKey;
}
```

The problem I have is with Coder, none of the if statements are ever true, and rtnstring is always just "".

```
public String Coder(String[] key, String msg){
    String rtnstring = "";

    for ( int i = 0; i < msg.length();i++){

        for (int x = 0; x<26 ; x++){
            if ( msg.substring(i, i+1) == alphabet[x]){

                rtnstring.concat(key[x]);
            }if (msg.substring(i, i+1) == " "){

                rtnstring.concat(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    return rtnstring;
}
```

Here is my logic for the coder method.

It goes through the String msg 1 letter at a time. It matches the letter with its index in the alphabet, then it creates a new string based on the index's in the given key.

Comment: In java, Strings should always be compared with equals method. You will find a good explanation here.http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/

Comment: this kind of question asked about 1-5 times per day. and the answer is keep flooding

Comment: @RafaEl This question has the interesting twist, though, that the best answer is "don't use `String`".

Comment: @chrylis I think most of us agree with that. but i'm getting angry to see _"for string comparision, use equals(), equalsIgnoreCase()"_ kind of answers :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method from the String class. When you use `==` you are comparing the reference variable of two objects (which is not same in your code)

```
  +----------+                        +----------+
  |          |     What you need      |          |
  |  "   " <-------to compare-----------> "a"    |
  |          |                        |          |
  |          |                        |          |
  +----------+                        +----------+
       ^                                   ^
       |                                   |
       +              What you             +
   rtnstring <------+ erroneously +---->  msg
                      compare
```

Answer (score 9):

You want to use `char` instead of `String` for this; `char` values are individual characters, which is what you're working with. To compare `String` objects, you need to use `equals()`, but you can use `==` with `char`s.

Answer (score 2):

First of all instead of `substring` use the function `charAt` and then change the `String[]` to `char[]` i.e.,

```
private char[] alphabet =  {'a', 'b', .... , 'z'};
```

and

```
if ( msg.charAt(i) == alphabet[x])
```

In your example you are using `String` and when you use `==` then it compares the references and `substring` function will always return a new `string` for avoiding such problems use `equals(String)` instead .

To provide better understanding read the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) The example will provide you all the details how `String` are initialized and what is meant by `references` equality.

Answer (score 1):

**String** should be compared using `equals()` method, not *==*. equals() method is used to check the *String* literals are *meaningfully equivalent* or not

```
public String Coder(String[] key, String msg){
    String rtnstring = "";

    for ( int i = 0; i < msg.length();i++){

        for (int x = 0; x<26 ; x++){
            if ( msg.substring(i, i+1).equals(alphabet[x])){

                rtnstring.concat(key[x]);
            }if (msg.substring(i, i+1).equals(" ")){

                rtnstring.concat(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    return rtnstring;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( msg.substring(i, i+1).equalIgnoreCase(alphabet[x])){
    rtnstring.concat(key[x]);
}
if (msg.substring(i, i+1).equalIgnoreCase(" ")){
    rtnstring.concat(" ");
}
```

Your comparison should use [`equalIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) or [`equal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in case of strings but if you want to just compare characters

```
// first define array of characters
private char[] alphabet =  {'a', 'b', ..... 'z'};
// then you can use ==
if ( msg.charAt(i)== alphabet[x]){
    rtnstring.concat(key[x]);
}
if (msg.charAt(i) == '\b')){
    rtnstring.concat(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private Char[] alphabet =  {'a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i','j', 'k', 'l','m', 'n', 'o','p', 'q', 'r','s', 't', 'u','v', 'w', 'x','u', 'z'};

I turned your String into char(characters) for you. You can continue to use ==if you choose to change to char.